# Gulp watch causes infinite loop

Tags: javascript, gulp

When I run gulp js and make a change to a JS file it gets into an infinite loop when it gets called

Why is calling build from gulp.watch not ever returning?

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var browserify = require("browserify");
var reactify = require("reactify");
var source = require("vinyl-source-stream");
var watch = require("gulp-watch");

function _bundle(config){
    return browserify({
        entries: ['./main.js'],
        transform: [reactify]
    }).bundle();
}
gulp.task('default',function(){
  "use strict";
  _bundle()
    .pipe(source('build.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
gulp.task('build',function(){
    "use strict";
    _bundle()
        .pipe(source('build.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));

});



gulp.task('js', function() {

    //gulp.watch(['./*.js'], ['default']);
    gulp.watch(['./*.js'],['build'])
});
```

//

Comment: 'not returning' - it is not supposed to, it is supposed to be 'watching' for changes

Comment: @SimonH true, that was poorly worded.  The issue is that the function gets into an infinite loop, calling _bundle continuously after a single change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are specifying `watch` on all .js files (`*.js`), and triggering `build` when any of them change.
Build in turn calls `_bundle`, which is going to result in modifications to `main.js`
Since `main.js` matches the `*.js` of `watch`, `build` will again be triggered, and now you have a cycle that ensures infinite looping.

Comment: That was the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes I have the same problem, how do you omit the bundle file from being watched?

Comment: I figured it out :) I used this (if anyone comes from google like I did):

`gulp.watch(['webroot/js/**/*.js', "!webroot/js/bundle.js"], ['default']); `

The `!` character makes the watcher ignore this file.